# let compiler do the work by overloading methods doesn't work

Tags: java, compiler-construction, overloading, strong-typing

Suppose I have the following class Structure

```
public interface Searchable{

    public boolean matches(String text);

}

public abstract class AbstractSearchable implements Searchable{

    private String name;


    public boolean matches(String text){
        return null != name && name.startswith(text);
    }
}
```

Most of my domain Objects inherit from `AbstractSearchable`, but there are a few which are only `Searchable` and implement their own behavior.

Then I have a Test as Following:

```
public class SearchableTest<T extends Searchable>{
    public void testSearchable(){
        //get an instance which is either Searchable or AbstractSearchable
        T item = getSomeTestItem();
        checkItem(item);
    }

    public void checkItem(Searchable searchable){
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement your own check for Searchable and Override checkItem(Searchable)!");
    }

    public void checkItem(AbstractSearchable item){
        //here i can Implement the Test using the name from AbstractSearchable
        //... implementation
    }
}
```

I thougth, that if the Return of `getSomeTestItem` is AbstractSearchable the compiler will find this out and passes it to the 'right' `checkItem` method. I read somewhere ( I really forgot where), taht the Java compiler always figures out kind of the 'best fit' (meaning TestItem is actually 'more' AbstractSearchable than Searchable). Unfortunately it does not, and all `AbstractSearchables` gets passed to the 'wrong' checkItem` method.

I'm aware of the quickfix

```
public void checkItem(Searchable searchable){
    if (searchable instanceof AbstractSearchable){
        checkItem((AbstractSearchable)searchable);
    } else {
        throw new UnsupportedOperationException("Please implement your own check for Searchable and Override checkItem(Searchable)!");
    }
}
```

but I really hate `instanceof` checks. Is there something I can do, to make this work?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you say the *compiler* tries to find the best fit - but the kind of object returned by `getTestItem` will only be known at runtime and you only declare it to be a `T extends Searchable`. So the best fit you can find at compile-time is `checkItem(Searchable searchable)` :-(

Comment: What is if `getSomeTestItem` does NOT actually return a `T`, but is implemented as `public DomainObjectWhichIsAbstractSearchable getSomeTestItem()`?

Comment: The only thing the compiler knows is what you tell it - and you only tell it that `ìtem` is a `T` that `extends Searchable`. I edited my answer and hope it's more clear now.

Answer (score 0):

For the desired class structure I think there is no way to achieve exactly what you want, because `T` is declared as `extends Searchable`, which can be `Searchable` or `AbstractSearchable`, and the proper method will be found based on this information, i.e. the behavior you described and do not want.

In order to avoid this problem, you might want to refactor your classes to avoid inheritance of `AbstractSearchable` and instead delegate `matches()` calls to some implementation provided to domain object, or maybe in the service.